# What's a good alternative to firing a stored procedure 368 times to update the database?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, vb.net, stored-procedures

I'm working on a .NET component that gets a set of data from the database, performs some business logic on that set of data, and then updates single records in the database via a stored procedure that looks something like `spUpdateOrderDetailDiscountedItem`.

For small sets of data, this isn't a problem, but when I had a very large set of data that required an iteration of 368 stored proc calls to update the records in the database, I realized I had a problem. A senior dev looked at my stored proc code and said it looked fine, but now I'd like to explore a better method for sending "batch" data to the database.

What options do I have for updating the database in batch? Is this possible with stored procs? What other options do I have?

I won't have the option of installing a full-fledged ORM, but any advice is appreciated.

---

*Additional Background Info:*

Our current data access model was built 5 years ago and all calls to the db currently get executed via modular/static functions with names like `ExecQuery` and `GetDataTable`.  I'm not certain that I'm *required* to stay within that model, but I'd have to provide a very good justification for going outside of our current DAL to get to the DB.

Also worth noting, I'm fairly new when it comes to CRUD operations and the database.  I much prefer to play/work in the .NET side of code, but the data has to be stored somewhere, right?

---

Stored Proc contents:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spUpdateOrderDetailDiscountedItem] 
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @OrderDetailID decimal = 0,
    @Discount money = 0,
    @ExtPrice money = 0,
    @LineDiscountTypeID int = 0,
    @OrdersID decimal = 0,
    @QuantityDiscounted money = 0,
    @UpdateOrderHeader int = 0,
    @PromoCode varchar(6) = '',
    @TotalDiscount money = 0

AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Insert statements for procedure here
    Update OrderDetail
    Set Discount = @Discount, ExtPrice = @ExtPrice, LineDiscountTypeID = @LineDiscountTypeID, LineDiscountPercent = @QuantityDiscounted
    From OrderDetail with (nolock) 
    Where OrderDetailID = @OrderDetailID

    if @UpdateOrderHeader = -1
      Begin
        --This code should get code the last time this query is executed, but only then.
        exec spUpdateOrdersHeaderForSkuGroupSourceCode @OrdersID, 7, 0, @PromoCode, @TotalDiscount
      End
```

Comment: 368 operations is not a lot.

Comment: Need to see the stored procedure contents, even if abstracted...

Comment: Nearly all ORM's would still make 368 database calls.. They just batch them up.

Comment: You could also consider that you're attempting to optimize prematurely... If your bulk process doesn't happen very often and/or doesn't get much bigger than 400 cnt. then you might not have to worry at all. You should collect some metrics before optimizing to make certain it'll be worth it.

Comment: I agree that there is some premature optimization going on here.  However, the 368 updates took 5 whole seconds to complete.  I'm not sure if the delay is in SQL Server or in the DAL code, but either way, that's kind of scary to me and I'd like to go ahead and solve for this issue before we ship version 1.0 of this enhancement.

Comment: do you call the proc with exactly the same parameters (other than @OrderDetailID)?

Comment: @Noel no, each param's value can and likely will be different, except for OrdersID and PromoCode.

Comment: @Ben: Are you using a separate transaction for each call of the stored procedure?  You might find it quicker to batch up many calls into one transaction.

Comment: @Andrew I think I might have been using a separate transaction for each call of the stored proc; our DAL may have been written to do that by default, I'm not sure.  However, following Adam's advice ended up being an excellent quick fix to my problem and essentially wrapped all of the stored proc calls into one command to the db.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

An easy and alternative way I've seen in use is to build a SQL statement consisting of sql_execs calling the sproc with the parameters in the string.  Not sure if this is advised or not, but from the .NET perspective, you are only populating one SqlCommand and calling ExecuteNonQuery once...

Note if you choose this then please, please use the `StringBuilder`!  :-)

**Update:** I much prefer Chris Lively's answer, didn't know about table-valued parameters until now... unfortunately the OP is using 2005.

Comment: This is probably the least invasive solution. +1

Comment: @Chris I saw it used to batch multiple database commands relatively cleanly from code - you still get the benefits of sprocs, but you need a little extra logic to encode the parameters into the string in a valid manner.  Not my favourite route, but understandable.

Comment: dont think you need to worry about parameterised queries if all you are doing is calling procs as these have their own query plan anyway?

Comment: @Noel sorry, don't follow.  The sprocs will be optimised yes, the OP was just curious how to send 368 commands without foreach-ing and refreshing the parameters of the command object.

Comment: sorry missread, I thought you were saying that a parameterised query would optimise it.

Comment: @Adam This solution ended up working perfectly only took about 5 minutes to make the change.  I ended up building a `List<string>` used with `String.Join(";", _myList)` to make the call and it went from taking 5 whole seconds to less than a second.  This is exactly the quick fix we needed, so much thanks!

Comment: +1 Excellent pragmatic solution. But, `StringBuilder`, really? Is the time to create 368 strings really significant compared with 368 stored procedure calls?

Comment: It would be substantially more than 368 strings if multiple concatenations occured in succession - 368 is assuming only one giant join :-) Yes it could be called a micro-optimization, but that's only if you do it the wrong way the first time, using the StringBuilder takes no longer to code and is more memory efficient in exactly this scenario - no brainer really even compared to the relative performance gains on high latency things such as db/network access.

Comment: @David possibly - but it gets the job done and keeps the sproc intact.

Answer (score 16):

If you are using SQL 2008, then you can use a [table-valued parameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510489.aspx) to push all of the updates in one s'proc call.

**update**
Incidentally, we are using this in combination with the [merge](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx) statement.  That way sql server takes care of figuring out if we are inserting new records or updating existing ones.  This mechanism is used at several major locations in our web app and handles hundreds of changes at a time.  During regular load we will see this proc get called around 50 times a second and it is MUCH faster than any other way we've found... and certainly a LOT cheaper than buying bigger DB servers.

Comment: I hadn't heard of those before. Thanks for the suggestion.  Could you show or link to an example of how you might use that in code both on the client and in the stored proc definition?

Comment: @Adam you beat me to it! Thanks!

Comment: I justed checked, and unfortunately we're using SQL Server 2005.

Comment: And the best part is it handles the single record insert flawlessly as well as the multi-record insert.  All insert/update/delete procs built for 2008 should consider this method.

Answer (score 3):

You can send the full set of data as XML input to the stored procedure. Then you can perform Set operations to modify the database. Set based will beat RBARs on performance almost every single time.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  What's an RBAR?

Comment: Ha. Yes, perfectly sums up the situation.

Comment: Blech. WTF? Serialize it to XML, then deserialize it, when going over a connection that doesn't require it and won't benefit? This makes absolutely no sense.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a version of SQL Server prior to 2008, you can move your code entirely into the stored procedure itself.

There are good and "bad" things about this.
**Good**

- No need to pull the data across a network wire.
- Faster if your logic is set based
- Scales up

**Bad**

- If you have rules against any logic in the database, this would break your design.
- If the logic cannot be set based then you *might* end up with a different set of performance problems
- If you have outside dependencies, this might increase difficulty.

Without details on exactly what operations you are performing on the data it's hard to give a solid recommendation.

**UPDATE**
Ben asked what I meant in one of my comments about the CLR and SQL Server.  Read [Using CLR Integration in SQL Server 2005](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345136%28SQL.90%29.aspx).  The basic idea is that you can write .Net code to do your data manipulation and have that code live inside the SQL server itself.  This saves you from having to read all of the data across the network and send updates back that way.

The code is callable by your existing proc's and gives you the entire power of .net so that you don't have to do things like cursors.  The sql will stay set based while the .net code can perform operations on individual records.

Incidentally, this is how things like heirarchyid were implemented in SQL 2008.

The only real downside is that some DBA's don't like to introduce developer code like this into the database server.  So depending on your environment, this may not be an option.  However, if it is, then it is a very powerful way to take care of your problem while leaving the data and processing within your database server.

Comment: @Chris you bring up a good point about possibly moving the code entirely to the stored proc.  The problem is that the "auto-discounting" logic is a little complicated and would almost certainly require using cursors in the stored proc. That seems harder to maintain to me from a code perspective.

Comment: @Ben McCormack: In that case you still have one more option available under certain versions of SQL server: the CLR.  But now we're treading into land that most people stay away from... with good reason. ;)

Comment: @Chris what do you man when you say that the CLR is an option when working with SQL Server?  Obviously, the CLR *is* the engine that runs .NET managed code, but what does that have to do with SQL Server?

Comment: @Ben McCormack: Updated answer to include detail on integrating .net and sql server.

Comment: @Chris That does sound incredibly powerful. Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: @Ben Another nice point about SQL CLR assemblies: they get serialized into the database, so you don't have to copy DLLs when moving your db from, say, dev to staging or production.

Answer (score 0):

Can you create batched statement with 368 calls to your proc, then at least you will not have 368 round trips.  ie pseudo code

```
var lotsOfCommands = "spUpdateOrderDetailDiscountedItem 1; spUpdateOrderDetailDiscountedItem 2;spUpdateOrderDetailDiscountedItem ... 368'

var new sqlcommand(lotsOfCommands)
command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

//execute command
```

Comment: This doesn't solve anything, and relies on your code to escape values, etc correctly, which is bad. Assuming a persistent database connection, the time it takes to send the command should be minimal. While you're technically combining all updates into one batch by putting them in a single SQL statement, you're not solving the problem of calling a sproc 368 times (which your concatenated SQL still does!). Also, this removes your ability to track errors on a per-update basis.

Comment: Well, I'm sorry but do you really think that reducing 368 round trips to one won't increase performance? It is also the least invasive change.  I appreciate you will need to escape values.  Yes, the whole batch will error rather than one proc execution, depending on the semantics of whats being done, you might want to rollback the whole lot, which is still possible with batching.  I've not used SQLCLR, so can't comment on it, from what I have read about it, this scenario could be a reasonable use for it.

Answer (score 0):

I had issues when trying to the same thing (via inserts, updates, whatever).  While using an OleDbCommand with parameters, it took a bunch of time to constantly re-create the object and parameters each time I called it.  So, I made a property on my object for handling such call and also added the appropriate "parameters" to the function.  Then, when I needed to actually call/execute it, I would loop through each parameter in the object, set it to whatever I needed it to be, then execute it.  This created SIGNIFICANT performance improvement...  Such pseudo-code of my operation:

```
protected OleDbCommand oSQLInsert = new OleDbCommand();
// the "?" are place-holders for parameters... can be named parameters, 
// just for visual purposes 
oSQLInsert.CommandText = "insert into MyTable ( fld1, fld2, fld3 ) values ( ?, ?, ? )";
// Now, add the parameters
OleDbParameter NewParm = new OleDbParameter("parmFld1", 0);
oSQLInsert.Parameters.Add( NewParm );

NewParm = new OleDbParameter("parmFld2", "something" );
oSQLInsert.Parameters.Add( NewParm );

NewParm = new OleDbParameter("parmFld3", 0);
oSQLInsert.Parameters.Add( NewParm );
```

Now, the SQL command, and place-holders for the call are all ready to go...  Then, when I'm ready to actuall call it, I would do something like..

```
oSQLInsert.Parameters[0].Value = 123;
oSQLInsert.Parameters[1].Value = "New Value";
oSQLInsert.Parameters[2].Value = 3;
```

Then, just execute it.  The repetition of 100's of calls could be killed by time by creating your commands over and over...

good luck.

Comment: I'd run this through a profile to make sure that the constructor and collection are really what's eating the time.

Answer (score 0):

Is this a one-time action (like "just import those 368 new customers once") or do you regularly have to do 368 sproc calls?

If it's a one-time action, just go with the 368 calls.
(if the sproc does much more than just updates and is likely to drag down the performance, run it in the evening or at night or whenever no one's working).

IMO, premature optimization of database calls for one-time actions is not worth the time you spend with it.

Answer (score 0):

**Bulk CSV Import**

(1) Build data output via string builder as CSV then do a Bulk CSV import:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188365.aspx

Comment: Manually saving your data to CSV and then loading the CSV is ugly.  Use `SqlBulkCopy` for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Table-valued parameters would be best, but since you're on SQL 05, you can use the [SqlBulkCopy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy.aspx) class to insert batches of records. In my experience, this is *very* fast.