# Is there a way to get the Nth index of a specified char in T-SQL? (Without Substring!)

Tags: sql, t-sql, string

I am trying to get the index of the Nth character inside a varchar(MAX). Right now I am cutting off the front end of the varchar so I only have to check for the first but With extremely large varchars the process is getting way too slow. I would like to parse through the varchar(max) and just keep track of what index I am at and get the next character I want AFTER that index. If I could do this without having to constantly cut off the front of a large varchar constantly I think it would increase performance a good amount. Thanks.

EDIT:
Right now to parse a large amount of text I use CHARINDEX to get the index of the char, THEN I SUBSTRING the text to remove up to that first index. Now I call CHARINDEX again (which effectively retrieves the 2nd index of that character inside the text). However, this SUBSTRINGING is very taxing on the system and I want to avoid it.

EDIT: Ah, sorry my title was very misleading, it should be more straight forward now.

Comment: Um... The index of the `N`'th character is `N-1`. Can you give an example?

Comment: Sorry I should have spent more time elaborating. Right now to parse a large amount of text I use CHARINDEX to get the index of the char, THEN I SUBSTRING the text to remove up to that first index. Now I call CHARINDEX again (which effectively retrieves the 2nd index of that character inside the text). However, this SUBSTRINGING is very taxing on the system and I want to avoid it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The built-in string functions are rather limited in T-SQL. You need to combine SUBSTRING(), CHARINDEX(), STRPOS() to do this, but it not fast operations.

Also you can use a tally table.

But i think the best way is to use CLR procedure for task like your. It will be more efficient and fast.

Comment: I see, that is how it was originally but I hoped to be able to make it a stored procedure so that it would be easily editable in the future. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

One way to increase performance when doing *procedural* work (as opposed to *set-based* work) is to use [CLR Integration with SQL Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345136%28SQL.90%29.aspx).  I got this tip from [Chris Lively in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3282254/whats-a-good-alternative-to-firing-a-stored-procedure-368-times-to-update-the-da/3282448#3282448) when asking a question about performance.  Although I haven't tested it myself, the documentation around CLR integration with SQL server suggests that the CLR is much more performant than T-SQL for procedural operations.  For set-based operations, though, use T-SQL.

Answer (score -1):

I think the [CHARINDEX](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186323.aspx) or [SUBSTRING](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187748.aspx) functions will solve your problem.

Comment: SUBSTRING, as I mentioned inside the text, is what is bogging down the runtime by an incredible amount. I would like to do this without SUBSTRING.

Comment: @danp: The question was edited, there was nothing about SUBSTRING or CHARINDEX. However, thank you for -1.